# What is the suitable verb form of this 'wish-clause'?

Tags: sentence-construction, verb-forms, wish

This is the item from a grammar book.

> Jim’s neighbors are going to move. He wishes they would move (move) soon.

I wonder if I change it to the following:

> Jim’s neighbors are going to move. He wishes they __________ (move) so soon.

By adding 'so', what should be filled in the blank? Does 'wouldn't move' make sense?

Comment: I *think* I'm right in saying ***so** [adverb]* is something of a "negative polarity" item in the cited context. So *He **doesn't** want them to move so soon* or *He wants them **not** to move so soon* are both fine, but *He wants them to move so soon* is relatively unlikely, and best avoided. The question to ask is *Does **so** refer to some contextually established "degree, extent"?* Note that in expressions like *He's so rude!* there's no such reference / comparison (to some other "degree of rudeness"). In that context, ***so*** just means ***very***, where it's not "negative polarity".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Frankly, some of your comments are very difficult to understand, even for native speakers. Can't you simplify them? Even I have to reread them three or four times and it's a real nuisance.

Comment: I'm not trying to teach *you* anything, so it doesn't really matter whether you find my text easy to understand or not. Someone (perhaps the OP here) upvoted my comment, and I'm guessing that implies someone found it useful / enlightening, so I don't see a problem. In any case, if someone doesn't understand me, they can always ask for clarification. (But we both know perfectly well *your* primary purpose in reading my comments isn't to enhance your own understanding - it's to see if I've said anything you can reasonably take issue with! :)

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence makes perfect sense with 'wouldn't move' and indicates the opposite position to the first sentence.. In the first it implies he doesn't like them whist in the second it implies he will be sorry to see them go.

Comment: No, wishes they would move so soon is wrong.